# Property of a matrix - $x^T A y\geq x^TAx$ implies $y^TAy>y^TAx$.

Tags: matrices, inequality, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

There is a $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

$A$ satisfies the following property for $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ and $x\neq y$,

$$x^T A y\geq x^TAx\Rightarrow y^TAy>y^TAx.$$

Is there any known matrix property that satisfies the condition?

For symmetric positive definite $A$'s, it is true, but this is a sufficient condition, not a necessary condition. For instance, if $x=(-1,-1)$, $y=(-2,-4)$ and $A=(7,0;0,-1)$, the condition is satisfied but $A$ is not a PD matrix.

Any type of help (hint, literature, solution) will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for the comment. But please check the second line. That property is only for $x\neq y$.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the comment. I got it. So, being a PD matrix is a necessary condition. Can it also be sufficient as well? As far as I checked, I needed the symmetry of A to have the property holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a real $n\times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies
$$x^T A y\geq x^TAx\implies y^TAy>y^TAx$$
for all $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$ with $x\neq y$ then $A$ is positive definite: For $y \ne 0 = x$ is
$$ 
x^T A y = 0 =  x^TAx\implies y^TAy>y^TAx = 0 \, .
$$

Conversely, if $A$ is positive definite and $x \ne y$ with $x^T A y\geq x^TAx$ then
$$
 y^TAy - y^TAx = \underbrace{(x-y)^T A (x-y)}_{> 0} 
+ \underbrace{(x^T A y - x^T A x)}_{\ge 0} > 0 \,.
$$

Comment: Wow, great! thanks!!!